# TensorFlow: Initial value without shape

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to implement the following code.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

def initw(a,b):
    tf.Variable(tf.sign(tf.random_uniform(shape=[a,b],minval=-1.0,maxval=1.0)))

bla = initw(a,b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run([bla], feed_dict={a:2, b:2}))
```

But I keep getting an error which states:

```
ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("Sign:0",shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I really don't see what causes the error.

EDIT:

I want to use `initw(a,b)` to initialize the weights of a network. I want to be able to do something like:

```
weights = {
    "h1": tf.get_variable("h1", initializer=initw(a,b).initialized_value())
    }
```

Where `a` and `b` are the height and width of a matrix.

Comment: Please update your question so we can see what you need this for. In this example there is no apparent need for the size of the variable to be dynamic, or even for the variable to be a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my eyes the error message is actually quite precise. But I understand your confusion. You probably do not really understand how Tensorflow works under the hood. You might want to start reading [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs).

The shape of the computational graph must be known before runtime. There can only be one axis in every variable or placeholder which is unspecified at compile time, it is than later at runtime considered to be the batch dimension.

In your case you are trying to use placeholders to specify the dimensions of a variable, which is impossible because the graph can not be compiled this way.

I don't know what you are trying to do with this but I would guess there is a way to achieve what you need. You can actually use the length of the batch dimension dynamically to draw a uniform vector of that size.

**Edit**: After you updated the question I feel like I was right about my suspicion. There is no need for `a` and `b` to be placeholders, just make them Python variables, like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Matrix shape must be known in advance, but can of course still be specified
# in some settings file or at the beginning of the python skript
A = 2
B = 2

W = tf.Variable(tf.sign(tf.random_uniform(shape=(A, B), minval=-1.0,
                                          maxval=1.0)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print(sess.run(W))
```

Comment: I also tried `a=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=(1,1))` which also did not work.

Comment: Yes of course it does not, because you are still using the placeholder as input to determine the shape of a variable, which is impossible. 
`tf.Variable(tf.sign(tf.random_uniform(shape=[a,b],minval=-1.0,maxval=1.0)))` that is the line which does not work. `a` and `b` can't be Tensorflow placeholders, they must be known before graph construction.

Comment: I updated my question. I hope you see now what I want to do.